# Show that this equation is valid.

Tags: functions

Here is the question.

> The elastic wave p has a constant speed anywhere on the location of the 2D plane.
> There are *n* points which are written as (*xᵢ*, *yᵢ*), where (*i* = 1, 2, ..., *n*).
> The time it takes to get from point (*xᵢ*, *yᵢ*) to (*x*, *y*) is written as *tᵢ*.
> Show that the equation is valid. (*t − tⱼ*)<sup>2</sup> ((*x − xᵢ*)<sup>2</sup> + (*y − yᵢ*)<sup>2</sup>) − (*t − tᵢ*)<sup>2</sup> ((*x − xⱼ*)<sup>2</sup> + (*y − yⱼ*)<sup>2</sup>) = 0 and *i, j* = 1, 2, ..., *n* (*i* does not equal to *j*)

I have tried this way so far.

(*t − tⱼ*)<sup>2</sup> ((*x − xᵢ*)<sup>2</sup> + (*y − yᵢ*)<sup>2</sup>) = (*t − tᵢ*)<sup>2</sup> ((*x − xⱼ*)<sup>2</sup> + (*y − yⱼ*)<sup>2</sup>)

(*t − tⱼ*) (distance to point *i*) = (*t − tᵢ*) (distance to point *j*)

(*t − tⱼ*) / (distance to point *j*) = (*t − tᵢ*)  / (distance to point *i*)

*t* / (distance to point *j*) − *tⱼ* / (distance to point *j*) = *t* / (distance to point *i*) − *tᵢ* / (distance to point *i*)

*t* / (distance to point *j*) − 1 / v = *t* / (distance to point *i*) − 1 / v

*t* / (distance to point *j*) = *t* / (distance to point *i*)

(distance to point *i*) = (distance to point *j*)

I am stuck. It only makes sense when point *i* and point *j* has the same distance from point (x, y). But I don't think this is how I am supposed to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).